# How to return a object in HttpResponseMessage in Web api mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

In one of my Get request, I want to return an HttpResponseMessage with some content. Currently I have it working as follows:

```
// GET api/Account/5
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetAccount")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAccount(int id)
{
    Account value;
    try
    {
        var myque = from x in db.Accounts where x.idUser==id select x;
        value= myque.FirstOrDefault();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent("[{\"Success\":\"Fail\"},{\"Message\":\"Login Fail\"}]", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent("[{\"Success\":\"Success\"},{\"Message\":\"Login successfully\"}],{\"Data\":"+value+"}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
}
```

I want to add value to HttpResponseMessage. Value will return a json normal.

```
[
    {
    "Success": "Success"
    },
    {
    "Message": "successfully"
    }
    Value will display at here  
]
```

Comment: You don't need to return the message which indicates success or not. Instead, using HTTP Code 200 OK is enough.

Comment: Your mean: HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, products);
    return response;

Comment: yes, Cuong Le is right, HttpResponseMessage by design contains whether the operation was successful or not. check http codes here - http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html Yes, in case if you want to pass additional information along with the response then you should add them in the response

Comment: My custome require me to do that?

Comment: @Cuong Le, I am getting HTTP Code 200. But I want to read/access the data from the URL which I have given. Can you please suggest me...!


Eg:

`HttpResponseMessage response = wc.GetAsync(URI).Result;`
`var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

I am getting the result as below in `Contents` variable as 
`<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class=" ltr"><head><title>ServiceNow</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1"></meta><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public"></meta><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=4"></link>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [ActionName("GetAccount")]... you should use IActionResult as the return type.

Otherwise if you want to use HttpResponseMessage, use -

```
[Route("api/GetAccount")]
```

Also, you can construct the output result like

```
return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = data };
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to format code into code blocks, so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jobject to return

```
return new JObject(<your dynamic object here>);
```